# There is no Default.aspx.cs file into my webapplications project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Before telling you anything i'd like to clear, I'm a completely beginner in ASP.NET. In fact, I started learning today ASP.NET.

So, I'm making an event that would bind my code with C# files. Well I'm good in C#.

But the problem is as I find into projects, there is no Default or any aspx.cs files here. Can you please help? Where can I find it?

[This tutorial](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/more-events/) says that to bind events, you need to write code in `.cs` files.

Here is my how my project is setup:

[image]

Comment: on source page click F7 , you will jump to code page if exist !! also read this please : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hds5k93(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @NiMa Is it good that i should jump directly there.. There is huge folders inside Web forms applications like font, content, bin, app_data etc..

Comment: @raju add a new webform in project name it Default.aspx

Comment: OPEN DESIGN Tab and right click on mouse then you can see your code view option in that..

Comment: @Raghubar As i mentioned you above, i want ***aspx.CS*** file not ".aspx"....

Comment: @raju i think there is problem in index.aspx which u have created. So try it, Add new web form in same project, It will resolve your problem.

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan there is no design tab, can you tell me .. where it is?

Comment: Look at the left bottom of screenshot "Design"

Comment: Show some Respect Pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have choosen a wrong project type while creating your project.For your purpose you need to do following

1. File>New>Project
2. On the left panel Go Visual C# > Web
3. Select ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Looking at your screenshot it seems you selected "ASP.NET Empty Web Application".You can add files to this as well but since you are a beginner its better to follow above steps.

Comment: Yes, i've selected as ***Empty web application***, But in ***Web forms*** applications, there is a huge amount of files collections.

Comment: Is it good that i should jump directly there.. There is huge folders inside ***Web forms applications*** like font, content, bin, app_data etc..

Comment: That should be fine those are standard set of files.Otherwise you can just go to solution explorer > right click > Add New Item> select web form

Comment: ".Otherwise you can just go to solution explorer > right click > Add New Item> select web form" ..... But dude.. It adds .aspx file.. while i want .aspx.cs file to bind my C# codes.. try to understnad

Comment: Yes ...but it will also have webform.aspx.cs file...just click on the arrow shown on the left side of the file or just right click the file and click on View Code